# Rambam's Mishneh Torah - Is a female pure after relations with a minor/gentile/animal?

Tags: women, rambam, animals, sexuality, minor-katan-child

In Rambam's [Mishneh Torah, She'ar Avot haTum'ah, 5:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Other_Sources_of_Defilement.5.19?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it is written:

> "גְּדוֹלָה שֶׁשָּׁכַב אוֹתָהּ קָטָן פָּחוֹת מִבֶּן תֵּשַׁע [אוֹ עַכּוּ''ם אוֹ בְּהֵמָה] הֲרֵי זוֹ טְהוֹרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר [(ויקרא טו יח) "וְאִשָּׁה אֲשֶׁר יִשְׁכַּב אִישׁ אֹתָהּ"] עַד שֶׁיִּהְיֶה הַשּׁוֹכֵב אִישׁ וּמִיִּשְׂרָאֵל כְּמוֹ שֶׁבֵּאַרְנוּ:"
>
> "When a minor less than nine years old - or a gentile or an animal - engages in relations with a mature female, she is pure, as indicated by Leviticus 15:18: "And a man who will lie with a woman." Implied is that the male must be a mature man and Jewish, as we explained."

How can a mature female be pure if she had intercourse with a minor (less than nine years old) or a gentile (how old?) or even worse, an animal!?

Comment: Doron this is referring to a specific type of ritual purity, not "purity" in general.

Comment: Even if this is the case, she is ritual pure if she had intercourse with an animal?

Comment: Yes, the Rambam didn't make this up, it's in the Talmud. It does seem strange if you haven't studied the laws of ritual purity before, I agree

Comment: Lomdus 4db.....

Answer (score 4):

The Rambam explains - the pasuk says 'וְאִשָּׁה אֲשֶׁר יִשְׁכַּב אִישׁ אֹתָהּ'... To exclude anything that isn't a fully grown Jewish adult man. Not that the Torah is condoning it, but it doesn't count as normal relations.

Comment: I see, well thank you for your explination. As יהושע ק said above, I havent studied the laws of purity before and that is why I was quite socked at Rambam's statement.